# Covering a div with an image

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a memory game, like [concentration](http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/memory/index.html).  Using jQuery, how do I cover over the square but not lose the contents that are inside the div?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zZzWw/

**Markup**

```
<div class="card">
     <div>Some Text brah</div>
     <img src="http://www.zombiegames.net/inc/images/Flaming-Zombooka-2.gif"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* I set width and height to the same as the image */
.card{
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;   
}

.card div{
     display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.card').click(function(){
       $(this).children('div').toggle();
       $(this).children('img').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Can just toggle between the 2 elements that are wrapped with a container element.

Comment: Ahh..  Elegant.  I knew I better ask on SO before I started going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Try regular CSS.  Put an image in the div with visibility:hidden.  Use javascript to toggle to visibility:visible.  Maybe set z-index as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS  to fill the div with the original image being the background.

Then change the CSS to have the new background image.